# Invertible Matrices with t

Tags: matrices

Suppose $B_t = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & t \\ t & 2\end{bmatrix}$

Find all real numbers $t$ such that $B_t$ is invertible.

Hi everyone, trying to teach myself matrices, but this is confusing me. can anyone tell me how to go by about it? Or show me how to do it for similar questions.

Thanks

Comment: for formatting matrices, google "format matrix tex" or "format matrix latex".

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

A matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is invertible if and only if $ad-bc \neq 0$.

You might encounter a quadratic equation while solving the problem.

Comment: So would the answer be that it can be any number other than +/- Sq Root of 6?

Comment: congratulations. Remark: to type plus minus square root, use \pm \sqrt{6}, surround it with dollar sign and you will get $\pm \sqrt{6}$

Answer (score 1):

a matrix is invertible if and only if the determinant is nonzero. The determinant in this case is $6 - t^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well for $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$,
the determinant of $A$ is given by $det(A) = ad - bc$.

so here $det(B_{t}) = 6 - t^2$,so a matrix $A$ is invertible if $det(A) \neq 0$ , so here $t^2 - 6 \neq 0$ or $t \neq +\sqrt{6}$ , $t \neq -\sqrt{6}$.

So the matrix $B_{t}$ is invertible for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$ except $\sqrt{6},-\sqrt{6}$.